# Horizontally shifted hidden rows in UIPickerView with 2 components

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a [`UIPickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) with 2 components:

[image]

The hidden rows however are shifted towards the center. I think it has to do with the space that `UIPickerView` places between the 'wheels'.

I don't see anything in iOS' rather brief documentation discussing how to prevent this.

Here's my code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return self.currenciesPicker.width / 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 50.0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    var cell: CurrencyPickerCell

    if view == nil
    {
        let width  = self.pickerView(pickerView, widthForComponent: component)
        let height = self.pickerView(pickerView, rowHeightForComponent: component)
        cell = CurrencyPickerCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height))
    }
    else
    {
        cell = view as! CurrencyPickerCell
    }

    let code = self.codes[row]
    cell.nameLabel.text   = Currency.names[code]
    cell.symbolLabel.text = Currency.symbols[code]

    return cell
}
```

When I let `widthForComponent` return half the picker's size minus 20, the cells just show up 20 point smaller. This creates empty borders on the left and right ends of the picker view. It does not change this weird 'parallax'.

- Does anyone have an idea what's causing this and how to prevent it?
- How should I calculate `widthForComponent` (is half the width of the picker correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is how the UIPickerView control is designed.  It's supposed to look like a couple of wheels sitting side by side that you are looking at from directly above.  It's a bit of a strange one considering all the push towards a flat design style Apple has made but there is no way to change it.

The only real options are to do it yourself, either completely manually or possibly subclassing UIPickerView and handling the drawing yourself, or to use a 3rd party control.

Comment: Is half the picker width correct? Any idea why the `UIDatePicker` looks better in this regard?

Comment: Correct for what?  You are not going to be able to get rid of the 'shifting' you are seeing no matter what you set that to.

Comment: I mean: Is it correct that the sum of all element widths is equal to the width of the picker?

Comment: It doesn't have to be if it's less I think they each get centred in their own half of the picker control.